# Obtain new HTML page with the full content of item after JSON FETCH

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch, queryselector

I made a JSON FETCH listing all the items in the main HTML file, and I mapped the data giving a href condition to the 'Page ID' category of my JSON.

I need to click on a determined 'Page ID' href and get a new HTML with all the content related to that value and stored in the JSON file. I'll prefer to open a new tab named with the 'Page ID' that I clicked and show the single content for that value.

Could you please give a hand with this issue?

### HTML and JS file

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4> TESTING - List of items </h4>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="app"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

fetch("../../model/data/output/json/20230508-025424.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        // convert the data to html
        const chunk = data.map(item =>                                                                 `<section>
     <table>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <h1><a href="${item['Page ID']}" target="_self">${item['Page ID']}</a></h1>
                     <div><span><b>${item['Page Title']}</span></b></div>
                     <hr>
                     <details>
                         <summary>View Content</summary>
                            <p>${item['Page description']}</p>
                     </details>
                     </td>
                     <td class="spacer spacer-right"></td>
                     <td class="side-title">
                 </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
 </section>`
            ).join('');
            // create a virtual container
            const range = document.createRange();
            // give it a context
            range.selectNode(app);
            // add the html, this converts the html into a collection of elements
            const fragment = range.createContextualFragment(chunk);
            // append the elements to the document
            app.appendChild(fragment);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### JSON file

```
[
      {
            "Page ID": 17411,
            "Page Title": "Luke Skywalker",
            "Page description": "Luke Skywalker is a fictional character and the protagonist of the original film trilogy of the Star Wars franchise created by George Lucas. Portrayed by Mark Hamill, Luke first appeared in Star Wars (1977),[v] and he returned in The Empire Strikes Back (1980) and Return of the Jedi (1983). Over three decades later, Hamill returned as Luke in the Star Wars sequel trilogy, cameoing in The Force Awakens (2015) before playing a major role in The Last Jedi (2017) and The Rise of Skywalker (2019). He later played a digitally de-aged version of the character in the Disney+ series The Mandalorian, appearing in the second-season finale, which premiered in 2020, and The Book of Boba Fett, in the sixth episode, released in 2022.",
            "Tags": "Jedi",
            "Page Depth": 1,
            "Unique Page Views": 7513,
            "Average Time Spent on Page": "00:06:59",
            "clean_page_title": "luke skywalker"
      },
      {
            "Page ID": 17416,
            "Page Title": "Leia Organa",
            "Page description": "Princess Leia Organa is a fictional character and one of the main protagonists in the Star Wars franchise, portrayed in films by Carrie Fisher. Introduced in the original Star Wars film[c] in 1977, Leia is princess of the planet Alderaan, a member of the Imperial Senate and an agent of the Rebel Alliance. She thwarts the sinister Sith Lord Darth Vader and helps bring about the destruction of the Empire's cataclysmic superweapon, the Death Star. In The Empire Strikes Back (1980), Leia commands a Rebel base and evades Vader as she falls in love with the smuggler Han Solo. In Return of the Jedi (1983), Leia helps in the operation to rescue Han from the crime lord Jabba the Hutt and is revealed to be Vader's daughter and the twin sister of Luke Skywalker.",
            "Tags": "Rebel Alliance",
            "Page Depth": 8,
            "Unique Page Views": 11044,
            "Average Time Spent on Page": "00:45:29",
            "clean_page_title": "leia organa"
      },
      {
            "Page ID": 17417,
            "Page Title": "Han Solo",
            "Page description": "Han Solo is a fictional character in the Star Wars franchise created by George Lucas. The character first appeared in the 1977 film Star Wars portrayed by Harrison Ford, who reprised his role in The Empire Strikes Back (1980) and Return of the Jedi (1983). Ford returned to the role for The Force Awakens (2015), as well as a brief cameo in The Rise of Skywalker (2019). In the spin-off film Solo (2018), a younger version of the character is portrayed by Alden Ehrenreich.",
            "Tags": "Smuggler",
            "Page Depth": 5,
            "Unique Page Views": 3281,
            "Average Time Spent on Page": "00:34:54",
            "clean_page_title": "han solo"
      }
]
```

### HTML view

[How the main HTML looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrOOx.png)

### The single HTML that I need when click on item with determined ID

[How the output HTML would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RywXW.png)